# Parts of Speech, Stanford Core NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

**It may be that he is bargaining for the Chancellorship, which he is certainly not fit for.**

In the above mentioned sentence, the Stanford Parser refers the word **bargaining** *Parts of Speech* as **NN** which signifies that this word is a **noun** here , however as per the use of the word in the above sentence, it should have been a **VERB** .

Could anyone clarify on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, in your sentence above, the word is a verb. The Stanford POS Tagger calculates tags based on a bidirectional approach. The POS tag of a word is calculated based on the context it appears in, meaning that two words before and two words after are considered. Based on that the algorithm outputs the tag which is most likely to be correct. The tagger does not claim the output to be correct. It is just more likely, that *bargaining* is a noun in this sentence.

You could train your own POS tagger, if you really want a correct output. But that requires a lot of effort. For more information, take a look [here](http://renien.com/blog/training-stanford-pos-tagger/) and [here](https://medium.com/@klintcho/training-a-swedish-pos-tagger-for-stanford-corenlp-546e954a8ee7).